# Apache: Dynamically set the DocumentRoot inside a VirtualHost section?

Tags: linux, apache, web-development-server

In an Apache VirtualHost section, is it possible to dynamically assign a DocumentRoot based on hostname instead of having one VirtualHost section for each hostname?

I have many hostnames that all share the same wildcard certificate and many other parameters. So it would be much better to have them all inside one VirtualHost section and set the DocumentRoot bases on the hostname.

Comment: You can use `Include` statements to share common settings between virtual hosts. This way you can still have separate log files for vhosts, etc.

Comment: @ypnos True. But I prefer a single conf file.

Answer (score 1):

The module [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) offers this functionality. Instead of `DocumentRoot`, you would define `VirtualDocumentRoot` where you can embed variables from the request.

Simplest example from linked documentation:

> ```
> UseCanonicalName    Off
> VirtualDocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%0"
> ```
>
> A request for http://www.example.com/directory/file.html will be satisfied by the file */usr/local/apache/vhosts/www.example.com/directory/file.html*.

Comment: Yes, but how can I use that to assign different document roots to different hostnames? Say I want the DR to be "/something/" for the hostname "joe.example.com" and "/else/" for "tim.example.com".

Comment: You might combine it with *mod_rewrite*.