# Apache: Dynamically set Documentroot inside Virtualhost Section based on reverse-DNS Notation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vhosts, reverse-dns, mod-vhost-alias

we want to setup one apache-server via VHosts to do the following:
We want to route each of our mutliple domains to their corresponding location based on the domain-name (including subdomains, so the amount of Levels may vary) and their reverse-domain-name-notation (reverse-DNS) as directory-name.

For example we want to route `admin.example.com` to `/domains/com.example.admin/public` and `myshop.net` to `/domains/net.myshop/public`.

We know that to achieve this without reverse-DNS the Config should look like this (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969762/apache-dynamically-set-the-documentroot-inside-a-virtualhost-section) and [the mod_vhost_alias documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/domains/%0/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

The documentation only talks about rearraging single letters in the domain-name-parts.

We could think of a solution like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/domains/%-1.0.%-2.0.%-3.0.%-4.0.%-5.0.%-5.0.%-6.0/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

But we could imagine that when there are less (or unlikely more) domain-name-parts it would not work or accumulate leading/trailing dots or something else.

So is it possible and if so how do we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think there is no way to just reverse order of the parts in domain name. But I end up using this ugly solution. Just have multiple VirtualHost definitions, each wildcarding domains of different depth.

```
#For domains 5 levels deep like 'test1.project.dev.mydomain.com'
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.*.*.*.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /webroot/%-1.0.%-2.0.%-3.0.%-4.0.%-5.0/
</VirtualHost>

#For domains 4 levels deep like 'project.dev.mydomain.com'
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.*.*.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /webroot/%-1.0.%-2.0.%-3.0.%-4.0/
</VirtualHost>

#For domains 3 levels deep like 'www.mydomain.com'
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.*.com
 VirtualDocumentRoot /webroot/%-1.0.%-2.0.%-3.0/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I cannot edit your post but to make it complete I suggest you add also domains 2 levels deep.